# How to delete all emoji from Excel list of phrases?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

is there a way to fast clean all disturbing emoji from a long excel list of phrases?

Like this one?   " + 3 -8"

to be like             "+3-8"

Comment: This is easy with ***VBA***.  Is this approach Okay??

Comment: Is there a difference between "disturbing" emoji and other emoji?

Comment: Yeah VBA would be fine but don't know how to do it. Do you?